# Looking for a proof that $\pi$ is irrational using a series representation.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, pi

I'm searching for a proof that $\pi$ is irrational using a series representation for $\pi$. I've seen that Apery proved that $\zeta(2)$ is irrational by using the series 
\begin{align}
\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = 3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}
\end{align}
but can't find the proof. Since proving that $\pi^2$ is irrational also shows that $\pi$ is irrational this proof is interesting.

This is the only proof I've heard of (but can't find it) that uses a series for $\pi$.

Comment: What about [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Infinite_series)?

Comment: But is there any proof that $\pi$ is irrational using those series?